# JScript intellisense with ScriptManagerProxy

Tags: javascript, asp.net-ajax, intellisense, scriptmanager, javascript-intellisense

I've got a problem making my ScriptManagerProxy expose registered scripts.
When I add a ScriptManager, everything works as expected and the scripts are reflected correctly, but whenever I change it to a ScriptManagerProxy, every script, even the MicrosoftAjax.js, dissapears from the intellisense.

I believe there is some sort of bug with the proxy, but could anyone shed some light on how I can fix this. It's getting quite tedious changing the ScriptManager to and from a proxy all the time.

By the way, I'm using user controls with embedded script resources, if that's of any importance (it all works with the regular ScriptManager, so there's nothing wrong with the code).